# Does mvn archetype remove markdown titles?

Tags: maven, markdown, maven-archetype

At my company we have a default archetype which many teams use to base their projects. We're trying to add a default README.md to it with titles and subtitles. But we're struggling with an unexpected behavior.

We're trying to add subtitles using multiple number sign characters (e.g. ###). But in the generated project's README.md the whole line is missing! We opened the archetype package and checked that the line starting with ### is present, so the removal must take place precisely in the archetype:generate step.

Is there a way to prevent maven from removing such lines?

Answer (score 6):

At the top of the md file put

```
#set($h1 = '#')
#set($h2 = '##')
#set($h3 = '###')
#set($h4 = '####')
```

Then where you need to have the ### put

```
$h3 My header
```

This will replace the $h3 with ### when you use your archetype